# I'm attempting to generate barcodes and save them to a spreadsheet

Tags: vba, image, performance, clipboard

I am trying to come up with a better way to do the following code. it works as is but due to the issues with windows clipboard memory leaks it's not reliable and not very fast. If possible I want to assign the image being copied from word.application directly into an array or at least be able to bypass the clipboard been trying for days.

```
    Dim ShapeName As String
    Const BarcodeWidth As Integer = 175
    Dim ws As Worksheet, WdApp
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set WdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")

Do Until ActiveSheet.Cells(RowLoc, 1) = "End of File"

    ShapeName = ActiveSheet.Cells(RowLoc, 1)
    
    With WdApp.Documents.Add
        .PageSetup.RightMargin = .PageSetup.PageWidth - .PageSetup.LeftMargin - BarcodeWidth
        .Fields.Add(Range:=.Range, Type:=-1, Text:="DISPLAYBARCODE " & ShapeName & " CODE128 \d \t", PreserveFormatting:=False).Copy 
    End With

    Sheets("Barcode").Cells(RowLoc, 5).Select                                                'selects the location where the bar code will be pasted
    ws.PasteSpecial Format:="Picture (Enhanced Metafile)", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False 'Pastes the bar code at the current selection
    RowLoc = RowLoc + 1
    Selection.name = ShapeName
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
Loop
    WdApp.Quit SaveChanges:=False
    Set WdApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never found a way to store the images in excel however I figured out the best way achieve what I was going for is to create code that preps the data in the format I need then mail merge the result into a template creates the shipping labels I am going for.